# Complex exponential inequality .How to solve it?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Ok so I started learning calculus from Spivaks book and on first chapter exercises I have stuck on one inequality for a few weeks now. Even my math professor does not know how to solve it. I have used Mathematica software to find solution (Solution is obvious but hard to find mathematically).

So I was wondering if this community could offer some answers.
Here is the inequality: $x+3^x < 4$

I have found one method where we can take this as two functions,first function being $f(x) = x+3^x$ and second function being $g(x)=4$ and then graph them. From the graph we can see where is $f(x) < g(x)$ but I do not think it is mathematically rigorous enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inequality $x + 3^x < 4$ can be solved analytically.  First we manipulate the inequality into the form $a e^a > b e^b$ as follows:

$$
4 > x + 3^x, \\
4 - x > e^{x\log 3}, \\
(4-x)e^{-x\log 3} > 1, \\
(4-x)e^{(4-x)\log 3} > e^{4\log 3} = 3^4, \\
[(4-x)\log 3]e^{(4-x)\log 3} > 3^4 \log 3 = 3^3 \log 3^3 = (\log 3^3)e^{\log 3^3}.
$$

Obviously we at least need $4-x > 0$ to satisfy this inequality.  Now, for $t > 0$ the function $f(t) = te^t$ is increasing, so if $a,b > 0$ and $f(a) > f(b)$ then $a > b$.  Thus

$$
(4-x)\log 3 > \log 3^3 = 3\log 3.
$$

From this it's immediate that $x < 1$.

Comment: Wow.This is jaw-dropping.Thanks for your answer

Comment: @VanioBegic, you're welcome.  For future reference, many such equations/inequalities involving a linear term and an exponential term can be solved using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  I approached this problem by nudging the inequality toward a place where I could apply it (something like $ae^a = c$) but it turned out that I didn't need to reference it explicitly after all.

Comment: This is a spectacular answer! If it were possible, I'd upvote 10 times!

Answer (score 4):

The functions $x$ and $3^x$ are monotonically increasing, and so is their sum $f(x)=x+3^x$. It is easy to see that $f(1)=4$, hence the inequality is true whenever $x<1$.

Comment: As a side note, I don't think there is a way to solve this analytically; we come by $x=1$ gives $f(1)=4$ via speculation.

Comment: Hmm,too bad I really was hoping for analytic solution,I had the same answer in my head before,but I thought speculation was not good enough.Thanks anyhow

Comment: @Clayton, you may be interested in reading [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/660953/5531) :)

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Thank you for bringing it to my attention!